# Не сохраняются изменения в базе данных

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Организовал связь один к одному между двумя таблицами базы данных, одна таблица Users, вторая UserProfiles. Модели следущие:

```
public class User {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public UserProfile UserProfile {get;set;}
}

public class UserProfile {
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Users")]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public User User {get;set;}
}
```

В базе данных созданы две таблицы, Users, UserProfiles, в UserProfiles внешний ключ на Users

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.UserProfiles_dbo.Users_Id] FOREIGN KEY([Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([Id])
```

В DbSet, databaseContext'a добавлены обе сущности (`DbSet<User>, DbSet<UserProfile>`)

При работе с User, делаю так, получаю ее из репозитория, затем создаю UserProfile, пытаюсь выпонлить update для репозитория но запись для userProfile не создается. Подскажите пожалуйста куда копать, что бы разобратсья с проблемой.

Как работаю с репозиторием :

```
var user = usersRepository.get(p=> p.Id == Id);

user.UserProfile = new UserProfile{
     Id = user.Id,
     User = user
};

usersRepository.Update(user);
```

В репозитории сохранение выполняется следующим образом:

```
var properties = new EntityProperties<TEntity>(entity);
properties.Store();
context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
сontext.SaveChanges();
context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
properties.Restore();
```

Comment: `public virtual UserProfile UserProfile {get;set;}`

Comment: Все равно не сохраняет.

Comment: SQL профайлером глядели? Подключаетесь к серверу баз данных или к файлу?

Comment: Подключение происходит, запрос тоже выполняет, но при update обновляет только users

Comment: Может Вы пытаетесь обновить несуществующий `UserProfile` ?